# how to send DTMF tones over sinch javascript web to PSTN calls?

Tags: sinch, dtmf

I have been looking for a long time but cannot find anything regarding this little quest of mine. I have successfully implemented the sinch sdk into my system and its calling perfectly fine. Now I'd like to send DTMF tones if the call is answered by a PABX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi on the call object there is a sendDTMF method DTMF key must be in [0-9, #, *, A-D].
Ios:

```
[call sendDTMF:@"1"];
```

https://download.sinch.com/docs/iOS/latest/reference/html/Protocols/SINCall.html#//api/name/sendDTMF:

Android

```
call.sendDTMF("1");
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer, now when I call this method the DTMF tone gets way more time for the machine to recognize, like more than 10 seconds, how do we minimize the time it takes for sinch sdk to send the DTMF tone?

Comment: Are you having the same problems with iOS and Android (do you use them?)

Comment: No we aren't using Android and iOS